# How can one configure Atril to correctly display the diacritics in an epub document in spanish language?

Tags: mate, epub

When using the Atril epub reader (default in ubuntu mate) to visualize a spanish document, the diacritics are not being correctly displayed (there are strange characters instead). Other viewers like calibre, okular and
lithium (android app) display correctly the diacritics. I have other documents in french, but this problem does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

First. Unpack the epub file (rename it to .zip and then unzip it)

Second. Put the following line as the first line inside all html files
inside the 'OEBPS/Text' folder:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>

(you can use the 'sed' command for this step)

Third. Pack the files using the following command (there's a specific
way of doing it, just zipping the file won't allow the apps to recognize
the epub format):
zip -rX ../myfile.epub mimetype META-INF/ OEBPS/

Probably this will be solved in some Atril's future release. By now
you can use the procedure above and maybe create a script to automate
the process, just in case you have too many files with this problem.